# Google Docs Scripts - Missing parenthesis on setValue for autorefresher

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm stuck with a single script just to setValue as "" and then set a formula of Importrange. Basically i'm doing this to have the data update quicker as i will set a trigger for each 5 minutes.

I'm receiving an error message about missing parenthesis. I've read about inserting the 
"+" into string but i don't see how can i do it into this expression.

Can anyone help me out on that?

```
*function UpdateTarget() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Teste");
  sheet.getRange("B4").setValue("");
  sheet.getRange("B4").setFormula("=importrange("1pG8nVt-wB4Sf4KvaXT_-0";if(day(today()-weekday(today())+2)<10;"0"&day(today()-weekday(today())+2);day(today()-weekday(today())+2))&"."&if(month(today()-weekday(today())+2)<10;"0"&month(today()-weekday(today())+2);month(today()-weekday(today())+2)) &"."&if(year(today()-weekday(today())+2)<10;"0"&year(today()-weekday(today())+2);YEAR(today()-weekday(today())+2))&"!BY34:KF83")");
}*
```

Thanks in advance!

Blue skies,

Comment: Honestly, there is so much going on in line 5 that I can't really follow it to see what formula you're trying to set there.  From what I can see, you are setting the value of B4 to =importrange("blahblah"), then going off on a tangent of ifs.  Are those sheet names that are calculated based on today?  If so, then I think I know what's going on.

How about sharing the sheet (or an mockup version of it) so I can see how the rest of that formula is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have mismatched quotes. Use single quotes inside the double quotes. Its just a standard javascript syntax error.

Comment: Thanks Zig! It worked the script, but when it paste it the formula into the spreadsheet it will return an error message. That happens because with single quotes are not identified. Any ideas how to revert or adapt this?

Comment: Yes. Swap double for single and single for double in that script line.